# What is the side effect of disabling HTTP PUT verb on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

After the security team run penetration test aginst our SharePoint 2013 portal, they reported the following error:

**"HTTP PUT is enabled on the web server. The file /19fd6ed3e1.txt was uploaded to the server using the PUT verb, and the contents of the file were subsequently retrieved using the GET verb."**

From my experience, I know that we can disable an HTTP verb on a specific ASP.NET site by modifying web.config file as below:

```
<authorization>
  <deny verbs="PUT" users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

My question is: what are the list of functionalities that may be affected if I disabled the PUT verb (or, at least, make it available for authenticated users only)? and can I do that with a safer way like from Central administration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010, PUT verb is required for multiple files upload.
If you disable PUT verb, you can't use multiple files upload function.
I think this behavior is same as SharePoint 2013